# Computers hangs after running big script ubuntu mate 16.04

Tags: 16.04, crash, ubuntu-mate, mpi

I am using ubuntu mate 16.04 and i recently ran a mpi script that was intended to overload my cpu. After running, and killing, the script I started running into issues:
- A lot of simple commands (like ifconfig) would to get stuck and hang.
- Trying to kill these processes, even with the -9 flag, doesn't work
- Rebooting the machine also hangs, I have force shutdown it using the button

After rebooting the machine I have never run the script again, but after a certain amount of time I again see commands starting to hang, or the network-manager service gets stuck, or some other odd thing happens, and I realize the symptoms re-appear and I have to reboot - which again hangs - and then I force shutdown.

I can't find anything that looks weird using top or ps. I ran the checkbox-gui hardware scan and didn't find problems.

This is the script I ran:
`mpirun -n 2 python bigScript.py -o /dev/null`
Where bigScript.py is just:
`2**10000000000000`

While it ran it did take 100% of my cpu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just updating that it seems that for now the problem went away by itself, no clue what solved it. Will update if it returns or if an official answer pops up

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that system is out RAM, and uses swap a lot.
I can't get result using one thread on system with 32 Gb RAM + 32 Gb swap.

You are trying to calculate `2^(1e13)`, it is very big number.

I can't calculate it even with quadmath:

```
// This is quad_pow.c
// Compile it with gcc quad_pow.c -lquadmath -o quad_pow; ./quad_pow
#include <stdio.h>
#include <quadmath.h>
#define LEN 10240
int main()
{
        char power[LEN], s_result[LEN];
        printf("Please enter `power` for 2^(`power`):\n");
        scanf("%s", power);

        __float128 result = powq(2, strtoflt128(power, NULL));

        quadmath_snprintf(s_result, LEN, "%Qf", result);

        printf("2^%s = %s\n", power, s_result);
        return 0;
}
```

The last I can calculate is `2^16383`:

```
2^16383 = 594865747678615882542879663314003565381722343548255118736337410616630679090241843452244297736306019957557718742419654629448833690654343713137262349170782503040435817183002448761071625809765723422976172854741067923518323732415492392357140483922807069238022169202443061452643427656618079347999942895053178509060407681660390482161856378582145306703437601208682661975133940044533758686135305417823772877890396715811106725951908929815345155671925328769680324822596641589145883829482702642556778067184896640862944007954207337644916269031709617444299949490311557012560837236025936219660661599201471352670683475637369507296908449144497222586700182308964188569037205672895924286797538585218822095871944822442688842369161120304119539530699737837667369892008245871310742614507423836167988948579198667113174867405720826538879125494463015447394802338076552128630070903411513794001720975727663850799035640794798584706982804219752491585627531141013313100024021074904100001030496716840618811928940313739863536438741419219352524017082316668506692702999020350954331193650802509094131286861883139620399465858854403950870132703965488209824438934802008758845969343994044004472125629413484844182097066972890078922182473026356827727453163593714265947550139347559661748404351815218096963796346172410406417148682239343431032084521229277568266027525254094945933423431899958823773645685786750350507598779548726520016515760341759108247097818348038874055299142450671805734607137060905247538989637778322582491925031025533258542323684732018320284669732418586091676478436956021320001805809394639097855026047281380653351775920165055322550997717583813344334813881910302171240178953207677106366473378036503453544435248062525034078329626380648832032749173746330899412031156105204637292282793632423208825080061587937017363130978644540733098825776915372212354849317376813885178113563072526274562614724020074557397840679937984256404287622135935727727042447493077510397403490469607829027659582820840552983227079975738454291564860751649408292571036530740444010884909169208564698439185729787923026291571464223624851849274062647887960468225011325713624974790354101983041423775460945576066660524005986941818288912766662994426078162719667510657656067040695225510627681853951747958481562962100583938595054467627957269744108448558971634686804319537236396375558357563553198212540676776568606776445269901301489322659897550488216469545962330114439456450327105059143649149353691079858592284770257701514586653646227195894784337109820380725586800308876093495956683418516943600791035812934123566552256657548637356721364170303321445203248318052221608876405613735014581429046863850524823249770110491990966393306602127113232121844805053714961598819340772918780886767784492268026813617212138552880462432011890814832763157455453480244036737608502560568155935219962881254333016283106875208347859959837111605303362360686735617010806770356094119954850985971972173740157108951943158883889960769946088667172184453775159400416773426172185163544642073750820294724241000627118693340037228670955466887445979840508258034553074952786212905447793469416533745102450184312083150984276502843520142547725242420036764321913285201883578643256190127554977259428506738294094650002069424857941569933035773787408238363817558217731402200556355696264590285397096711343409176606399534486123848595737134078956097986897096403649443476180550440132129400660464020005964076985400565370669775001649507962489129968487179363143071990260056227184635557041873959503901703298160676708502034434721702736070337981820498702504612901752836363232547753133669634446212182280948830953449212093385245517672040199624163548955856440570085192091029300807379142100375091750164679249845932033295269830354534768690800943839523328879827294000968558885672349163214396311447169008056222766769723543731024881704573771049624407760697964694003855586008947448896853302136740492580514407729393955580489556711216778774585452721013198637847641603652665922709995374673905262003097098600295826073933596848127168932490801916573177100850314408973588759057608837176008255586173863863537610028088874109464298579173372270668553679213878959830281291941911631089480845893613059432816382467144386202929877438879934617765326964968950596805834503736177373180382300936221015689972069912183414349395106461498087096364312945860028806254674550241272982076023238962557223250366082054549672629899727845047788394343198743530974427374512431803960928917102896898594417389828136739556194292853212418189536177705143393509263700826967109944180530974835980527534343480734009517814874712043293597520502202457633238136380535255784193531700632068258618605704958229398173812474607952266968605468760232899150087704008769431156359521180518564669448293014075023298039436222182782240272844516787977851494198359872264106492071289241977002542132163865420492710010704534742706160402634260047073399438055207291585195236991244449614045909106967144147839858684971576230223513645334982033408.000000
```

It corresponds with [`#define FLT128_MAX_EXP 16384` in *quadmath.h*](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libquadmath/quadmath.h#L155)

Please take into account that `log10(16383) = 4.2143934`, three-fold smaller than `13`!

WolframAlpha can calculate [until 2^(1e9)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E(1e9)).

If you need to measure system performance, you should [use LINPACK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-benchmarks-suite) or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
So the reason for the calculation was to intentionally fill up  2 cores of my cpu to 100% and look at it on top and kill it. I wanted to illustrate the kill command to someone, and chose this dumb way to do it, I didn't actually need a result.
I have 16GB of RAM and a dual core i7 (so 4 cores hyper-threaded). Using htop my ram and cpu are under-utilized. Also If it was a ram issue why would a reboot not solve it? With this info does it still seem like a ram issue to you? How could I test it? 
Also I think I might have ran the pure python at some point (no mpi)

Comment: If you want to test RAM independently - reboot, hit `<Shift>` and select *Memory test (memtest86+)* from GRUB menu. You can fill your cores better with LINPACK, and do not forget to monitor temperatures (with `sensors` or `xsensors`).